# Adding an array member to Grails scaffolding

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have a domain class with a Collection of simple Strings as one of it's members

```
class Customer {
    String name;

    static hasMany = [ aliases:String ]

    static constraints = {
        name blank:false
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if I can add the aliases to the grails scaffolding? and if so, how?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails does not do scaffolding for arrays. The hasMany is designed to be used with another domain class, not a variable. Using hasMany with a domain class will generate automatic scaffolding. For example

```
class Customer {
    String name;
    static hasMany = [ aliases:Alias ]
    static constraints = {
        name blank:false
    }
}
class Alias {
    String alias;
    static constraints = {
        alias blank:false
    }
}
```

This would create two tables, customer and alias. A foreign key would be used to associate records in the alias table with a customer. The collection of aliases would be accessed by

```
alias[0].alias
```

If you have to use an array instead of another domain class you will have to write custom code for the user interface.

Comment: That's more or less what I suspected, though "The hasMany is designed to be used with another domain class, not a variable" is a little strong, it does support collections this way, and creates an additional table it just doesn't build the related scaffolding. Assuming no one comes along over the next day or so with an answer that proves us both wrong, I'll accept this answer.